# Pandas dataframe in the current loop retains content from previous loop which messes up frequency count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a for loop where I'm creating a dataframe called rel.
The rel from the first loop is fine but I noticed that my second and third rel contain the contents of the rel from previous iterations
Since I'm using the information contained in each rel for a frequency count, I would prefer the rel in each iteration to only contain data from that iteration.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
for var in range(1,3): 
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols) 
     
    rels = df.loc[df['location2'].isin(array)]
    rel = rels.assign(Index = range(len(rels))).set_index('Index')
    print(rel)
```

I have a large .xml file which I'm storing in df. Then I'm taking a subset of df {specifically rows that contain the values specified in array in its location2 column]

I've tried clearing the dataframe at the end of each loop but that didn't work.
I tried putting a del rel and del rels before and after print rel which deleted the dataframe but that didn't resolve the problem

This is my output:
[As you can see the second dataframe is about double the size of the first when it should be about the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmXWZ.png)

I encounter this problem on the third and fourth iterations as well, the dataframe is triple or quadruple expected length

Comment: It seems to me that you are repeating the same process multiple times. You start by creating a dataframe (df), then subset as stated, then create the same df, and subset it again, etc etc... Are you sure you want to create the same df on every loop ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Your question is missing part of the code: what is the relationship between `var`, `rows`, and `cols` for example.

Comment: Looping through a dataframe is not a good idea generally. See https://towardsdatascience.com/efficiently-iterating-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-7dd5f9992c01

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, the problem was that I was looping through the dataframe. Removing the loops fixed my count. Thanks y'all